# Unqualified dependent name bind in definition time (first phase0

Tags: c++, templates

In "thinking in c++" was written

To clarify and summarize: name lookup is done at the point of instantiation if the name is dependent, except that for unqualified dependent names the normal name lookup is also attempted early, at the point of definition.

What is a exactly example of unqualified dependent names attempted early ? I have no idea why this exception exists. Thanks in advance.

Explanation and clarificcation with example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example:

```cpp
void f(int);

template<typename T>
void g(T x) {
    f(x);  // Lookup of f here finds f(int)
}

void f(double);
struct S {};
void f(S);

int main() {
    g(0);  // Calls f(int) found through early lookup
    g(0.0);  // Still calls f(int) since f(double) can't be found via ADL
    g(S());  // Calls f(S) found via ADL
}
```

When calling `f(x)`, the candidate functions are names found via "normal" lookup + lookup in the scopes of all namespaces associated via ADL. The normal lookup can be thought of as semantically happening at the function template's declaration rather than any particular specialization's (`g<int>`, `g<double>` or `g<S>`) instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

Unqualified lookup with dependent function arguments considers:

- Functions (and variables) visible at the point of the template definition, AND
- Functions via ADL at the point of the template instantiation.

I think the quote is trying to say that a list of candidate functions might be built at the time of definition (the first half), then augmented right before the lookup during instantiation (the second half).

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo_unqualified : T {
    foo_unqualified() {
        b<T>();
    }
};
```

There is no `b`, hence there is an [error](https://godbolt.org/z/fobeP5Mff):

```
<source>:5:9: error: there are no arguments to 'b' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'b' must be available [-fpermissive]
    5 |         b<T>();
      |         ^~~~
```

Now consider this example:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo_qualified : T {
    foo_qualified() {
        foo_qualified::template b<T>();
    }
};
```

There is no `foo_qualified::b` defined anywhere yet, thats why the compiler here needs the keyword `typename`.

Only on instantiation the name is actually looked up:

```
struct bar {
    template <typename T>
    void b(){}
};

struct no_bar {};

int main() {
    foo_qualified<bar> f; 
    foo_qualified<no_bar> f2; // error
}
```

Instantiation of `foo_qualified<bar>` is fine. `foo_qualified<bar>` inherits from `bar` and now there is a `foo_qualified<bar>::b()` template. `foo_qualified<no_bar>` fails because the look-up fails (only now on instantation).

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c54rP5KnE)